# Mysql query for sorting Time in hms format

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am trying to sort the data in Mysql descendingly based on the time for videos.

I have Video_Duration column in my database in which I store the time for videos in hms format( For example 1h54m3s, 9m3s, 0m3s).

When i try to sort the database using the query below I am getting the output like 9m0s, 9m0s first instead of time with more time(like 1h35m29s).

I am using the following query to sort the database

```
$sql = "select * from videos where Category_Name='$category' ORDER BY Video_Duration DESC limit 50";
```

Can you guys help me solve the problem

Comment: which data type used for video_duration?

Comment: Store time properly.

Comment: I use varchar(255) for video_duration

Comment: you have use int and convert your duration into seconds and store that value.

Comment: I got 1 million rows in my database. Is there any other way to solve the problem since database is already populated

Comment: then you have to convert in int when you retrieved  and after that you can sort

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your data is saved into the database not in the best way.
A varchar is sortable but follows the rules of alphabetical order. For example if I want to order the first 12 numbers with:

```
SELECT TOP 12 value
FROM number_in_order
ORDER BY value ASC
```

I will obtain something like this:

```
0
1
10
11
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

that is wrong.

The correct way to handle the length of your video files is using an INT field to store the amount of seconds and THEN via php retrive the value and format it in a user-readable way.

What I will suggest now is to create a new column called "NEW_VIDEO_DURATION" that will be a INT, then using a simple routine in PHP that read data from the varchar column, populate the new one with the correct value in seconds.

You can do something like this to parse your string value:

```
$stringValue = "1h3m40s";
$h = 0;
$m = 0;
$s = 0;

$splitted = $stringValue.split("h");

if($splitted.length > 0){
    $h = $splitted[0];
    $splitted = $splitted[1].split("m");
}else{
    $splitted = $splitted[0].split("m");
}

$m = $splitted[0];
$s = $splitted[1];

$intValue = ((($h * 60) + $m) * 60) + $s;
```

Now inside the var $intValue you have the correct time in seconds that can be stored inside the new column in the database.

Once you've converted all the values you can delete the old column as:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN video_duration
```

And rename the new column in:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN new_video_duration to video_duration
```

And you're done.

cheers